# Angular UI Accordion: Which item is open?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using the [Angular-UI Accordion-directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion), and I have a submit-button and need in the controller to find out which of list items are open. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the accordion group you can set what attribute you want to store the isopen value:

```
<accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups"  is-open="group.open">
  {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/qHzLiWDCmGggMFljQppN?p=preview